# After pressing the "win" key system hangs

Tags: 20.04

After pressing the "win" key system hangs after update to ubuntu 20.04. It shows the search bar and even finds and opens in the background searched application, however it is impossible to quit the search mode, pressing the "win" key again doesn't do anything, and impossible to use the running apllications. Reinstalled "gnome-software" but it didn't help. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps attempt a clean install instead, i.e., erasing the contents of the disk. Sometimes an upgrade causes unexpected issues. Before installing, you could check whether the problem does not occur in a live session.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, I will reinstall the program.